# Unable to get 3D effect when using getImageURI() from Google pie chart with only one value

Tags: javascript, image, charts, 3d, google-visualization

I have a php application application with dynamic google charts display. I put `'is3D': true` in chart configuration to put 3d effect, and it works perfectly.

When i try to convert the charts to img to export it after to PDF with dompdf :
`all_chart_divs.innerHTML = '<img src="'+allchart.getImageURI() +'">';`, I can't see the 3D effect in the image when there is only one value in the chart. But it works fine when the chart contains more than one value.

Here the chart before converting it to image: [image: before getimageuri]

And after convert it to img, I have that: [image: after getimageuri]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be reported to google. not an issue we can resolve...

Comment: I agree with user @WhiteHat, and if the OP stills interested, check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/zte0sc7a/3/) as an *alternative* - which is: adding to the single slice a `offset` of `0.02`. I think it's better to post an bug, but, the [github for issues with is empty](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) and the *[support google group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/support)* is not very clear to me if anyone can post or only group members.